# firebase realtime database not synced

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am testing my app before release. I have one physical device on which I tested the offline capability on Saturday. On Sunday I added two more results using another device and the released app.

When I know read the data from firebase I only get the cached data on the first device. How can I enforce fetching the data from the online database?

I have tried with `keepSynced(true)`, but I still get the same results. This is how I try and read the data:

```
await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .ref()
          .child(usersKey)
          .child(id5)
          .ref
          .keepSynced(true);
final userData5 = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .ref()
          .child(usersKey)
          .child(id5)
          .get();
```

userData5 contains 249 entries compared to 251 online. The diff of two comes from the two results added on Sunday.

How can I make sure to get the correct data?

I have also tried this now:

```
 await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .ref()
          .child(usersKey)
          .child(id5)
          .ref
          .keepSynced(true);

  var userData5 = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .ref()
          .child(usersKey)
          .child(id5)
          .get();

  await userData5.child(idKey).ref.set(user.uid); <- Gets stuck

  userData5 = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(usersKey).child(id5).get();
```

The idea is to update the value of the database (with the same as before) to trigger a synchronisation. I have seen that on other places. But when I try to set the data it just stops. Nothing happens and I don't get to the last `userData5 = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(usersKey).child(id5).get();`

Seems to be a similar solution here: https://medium.com/@naturallam/firebase-data-out-of-sync-during-initial-fetch-6e20b7a7c7b9

Comment: you can use firebase_paginate and make livedata:true

Comment: That does not seem to be for firebase-realtime-database?

Comment: yes,it's for firestore, sorry